# Can we move this sidebar to a different location depending on screen size?

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

We're running into a major issue with a particular sidebar on mobile pages. Have reached out to developers of the plugin (LearnPress) that manages the sidebar, but no response for about a week. I've played around with different display parameters for several of the divs, but to no avail.

This issue happens on the front page of an online course, which effectively **makes the entire course unusable for mobile users**.

This is the page in question: https://passpen.com/courses/life-insurance-practice-exam/

On desktop (768+ px width) the sidebar sticks in its normal location, the right side of the content. Works brilliantly. :) [Desktop screen size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk3Ju.png)

When viewing on a screen width less than 768px, the sidebar moves down to "near the bottom" of the content. The screenshot is Chrome responsive at 510 px. [Mobile screen size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBU7v.png)

As you can see, the sidebar has moved to the bottom of the content and pushes the footer down. Interestingly, if you open on an iPhone the footer moves to the bottom of the content and rolls under the footer.

Long story short, I need this page and sidebar to be usable for mobile users. The **best case scenario would be if the sidebar was just under the title on mobile with the rest of the content below it**, but if it had to be above everything (except the nav) then that would be fine.

I appreciate your time and advice. **Thank you.**

edit: On iPhone, it's actually not pushing under the footer. The content in the white box below the image is just not displaying at all.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this css:

```
.lp-archive-courses .course-summary .course-summary-content .lp-entry-content.lp-content-area .course-summary-sidebar {
  margin-top: -229px;
}
```

If the margin top is set to 0 then the image is in the correct position at the bottom of the page on mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be solving the issue. With this change the sidebar now shows up below the footer.  My goal is to have this sidebar appear above all of the content on the page, that way a user can locate and use it easily.